# Message to all Connected Clients (Using List)

Tags: java, multithreading, client, server, chat

So I have finally gotten most of this done but I came to a sort of halt. I have a server that can handled multiple connections concurrently, but the messages are only sent from each client to server respectively, I want the messages to be sent to server then pushed to ALL connected clients.

**Server**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;


public class ChatServerV2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {



        int portNumber = 8890;
        boolean listening = true;

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(portNumber)) { 
            while (listening) {
                new ChatServerThread(serverSocket.accept()).start();

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Could not listen on port " + portNumber);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }

}
```

**SeverThread**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ChatServerThread extends Thread{
    private Socket socket = null;
    private List<PrintWriter> writers = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();



    public ChatServerThread(Socket socket) {
        super("ChatServerThread");
        this.socket = socket;


    }

    public void run() {

        try (
            PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream()); //opens output stream
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream()); // opens the input stream
        ) {
            writers.add(output);


 //                 while (reader.hasNextLine())
 //             {
                ListIterator<PrintWriter> iter = writers.listIterator();


                //while(iter.hasNext()) { // while iterator is iterating
                //PrintWriter s = (iter.next()); // set the current selected     iterator from iter.hasNExt to variable
                String msg = reader.nextLine(); // read message coming
                while(iter.hasNext()) {
                    PrintWriter s = iter.next();
                    s.println(msg);
                    s.flush();
                    System.out.println("This should be what you see on your screen?");
                    System.out.println(msg);

                  }









            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ChatClient
{
public static final String HOST= "localhost";
public static final int PORT = 8890;

private ChatWindow window;
private Socket connection;
public static String user = "";




public ChatClient()
{   
    this.window = new ChatWindow(this);

    try {
        Socket serverConnection = null;
        try {
            //Connection//
            serverConnection = new Socket(HOST, PORT); //Connects to the          Socket
            connection = serverConnection;

            //Open Streams//
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(serverConnection.getInputStream());  //Reads input from the 
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(serverConnection.getOutputStream()); //Writes to output
            Scanner msg = new Scanner(System.in); //Testing loops
    }




            } finally {
            //serverConnection.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}




public void sendMessage(String message)
{   
    try {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.println(message);
        writer.flush();


    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}


private void start()
{           
    while (true) // while program is started and running
    {

        try {
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(connection.getInputStream());
            while (reader.hasNext())
            {
                window.printMessage(user+ ": " + reader.nextLine());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } //Reads input from the 
    }
}   




public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ChatClient chatClient = new ChatClient();
    user = Commands.getUser();
    chatClient.start();







}

}
```

**Chat Window (Provided and I cannot change)**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;   
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultCaret;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ChatWindow extends JFrame
{

private ChatClient client;

private JTextArea messageArea = new JTextArea(10, 32);
private JTextField inputArea = new JTextField(32);

public ChatWindow(ChatClient theClient)
{
    this.client = theClient;

    //when the user closes the window, make sure the user is logged out.
    addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
    {
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)
        {
            client.sendMessage("LOGOUT");
        }
    });

    // GUI COMPONENTS ------------------------------------------

    // MESSAGE AREA: All messages from all clients are displayed here
    messageArea.setEditable(false);
    messageArea.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    messageArea.setLineWrap(true);

    // make sure the scroll bar stays are the bottom
    DefaultCaret caret = (DefaultCaret) messageArea.getCaret();
    caret.setUpdatePolicy(DefaultCaret.ALWAYS_UPDATE);

    // INPUT AREA: Input area where client enters text message
    // The message is sent when the user presses enter
    inputArea.addActionListener(new InputAreaActionListener());

    Container content = getContentPane();
    content.add(new JScrollPane(messageArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    content.add(inputArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setTitle("Chat Client");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    pack();
    inputArea.requestFocusInWindow();
    setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * 
 * This method adds the message to the end of the message area followed by a
 * new line character.
 * 
 * @param message
 */
public void printMessage(String message)
{
    messageArea.append(String.format("%s\n", message));
    try
    {
        messageArea.setCaretPosition(messageArea.getLineStartOffset(messageArea.getLineCount() - 1));
    }
    catch (BadLocationException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private class InputAreaActionListener implements ActionListener
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String command = e.getActionCommand();

        // ask the chat client to send the message to the server
        client.sendMessage(command);

        inputArea.setText("");
        inputArea.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
}

}
```

So the way this works, when the client is started, it opens a gui and then I can type into the message box and it display what I type. It works fine, but I cannot figure out how when multiple clients are running, instead of the messages only being sent back to client that sent them, send them to all clients connected. I saw people said use ArrayList() to store threads and then use advanced forloop to cycle through but It doesnt look like it is working

Any thoughts?
I cannot change the SendMessage() method parameters as it was provided, and I cannot change window at all. I wrote Server, ServerThread completely by hand, and all of the actual code (excluding method header things with parameters) so that I can change. I cannot touch ChatWindow either

Comment: You have the loop which varies the socket `s` but you don't do anything with `s` inside the loop. But in fact you should have a list of `Printwriters`, not sockets; iterate over that; and write to each such `PrintWriter` in turn.

Comment: Just tried it and nothing? Still does the regular only print to one. Maybe I wrote it wrong

Comment: I changed list to the `List<PrintWriter> writers = new ArrayList<PrintWriter>();` and then I added `writers.add(output)` before the while statement in `ChatServerThread` class and it didnt do anthing. I made the S actually do something, `s.println(msg)`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You've missed everything I said starting from 'iterate over that' onwards. I suggest you fix that, and then if necessary post your new code in your question where we can read it.

Comment: *facepalm* iterate... smh Sorry about that! I will try that now

Comment: Posted updated code and still nothing is changing :/

Comment: You need to create the iterator *after* reading each line, and you need to synchronize on the list both when adding and when iterating.